# Adding many to many fields (M2M) manually in django?

Tags: django, model, m2m

I have a M2M field in my django model project. In my view I want to update a model instance with update() function. I know that for updating other ordinary fields we can pass a dictionary of the fields.
But how can I pass M2M field to update() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily add relations to the ManyToManyField using the [`add()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) function (outside of your `update()`):

```
blog.entries.add(post_1, post_2 ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

updating manytomany field you need to get instance of the sub class then apply update function.

class y:

```
 b = Text Field
```

class X:

```
 y = ManyToMany(y)
```

Code:

```
for y in x.y.all():
    if y: meet you condition for which row to update
       y.update(b='update')
```

I guess django does know support update() with M2M as it just create associate table for support and it can't understand which row in associate table to update.